# .htaccess 301 redirect from one subdirectory to another and preserve folder/directory structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I've done a lot of searching on how to do this, but none of the solutions seem to be working with this specific problem of redirecting from one subdirectory to another while preserving the original folder/directory structure.

For example I would like to redirect all incoming deep links from:
example.com/post/123 to example.com/archive/post/123

Basically I just want to move my original Wordpress blog from the root directory to a subdirectory, but I have a few popular incoming links and I don't want them to break.

Would appreciate any help or if anyone has had similar experience moving blogs yet retaining their incoming links.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: This can be done, but you need to provide more detail about your format. Are all of your previous links of a certain format? Is your new blog using the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out a while ago properly and wrote [an article about it on Medium](https://medium.com/stuff-that-happened-to-me/568bf26fba53):

Basically this is the code I needed in `.htaccess` in my root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(p/.*)$ http://phocks.org/historic/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(contact.*)$ http://phocks.org/historic/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(about.*)$ http://phocks.org/historic/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content.*)$ http://phocks.org/historic/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

For each of your links write as follows in the `.htaccess` file

```
redirect 301 /OldSubdirectoy/old/old.htm http://www.domainname.com/NewSubdirectory/new/new/new.htm
```

Write in this structure for each of your popular links to keep SEO.